# I am not able to find Fitness v1 in Step 1 in OAuth 2.0 Playground

Tags: api, oauth2-playground, fitness

On the Google OAuth 2.0 PLayground, I am not able to find Fitness v1 under Step 1: Select and Authorize APIs.
Please help me with the same as soon as possible.[tn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cy1jA.png)

[screenshot of the OAuth playground](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cy1jA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had the same problem. It worked for me with the steps described in this link:
https://www.programmableweb.com/news/how-to-develop-your-first-google-fit-app/how-to/2015/02/19

Check this part: "WIthin the oAuth Playground, select the gear icon on the top right then select use your own credentials. You will then enter the client id and client secret values you obtained previously."

After this, you can authorize access to your Google account and proceed with the steps to list data sources and get the number of steps for example.
You might want to check this link too: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/getting-started-with-google-fitness-rest-api-part-2/